# Gridview Row - value and column name

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I would like to get name of column which I click and value of this clicked row.

I found very good example but I`m not able to get this data which I want.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                e.Row.Attributes["onClick"] = "location.href='view.aspx?id_lekarza=" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Id_lekarza") + " &klikniete=" + "sss" + " '";
            }
        }
```

e.Row.RowIndex all the time 0?

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:alert('" + e.Row.RowIndex + "');");
                e.Row.Style.Add("cursor", "pointer");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your GridView you can add a template field like below :

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="44px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"
                            HeaderStyle-Height="40px" ShowHeader="false">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSelect" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/btnSelect.png"
                                    CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'/></ItemTemplate>
                            <HeaderStyle Height="40px"></HeaderStyle>
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="44px"></ItemStyle>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And in your C# codebehind You should create the RowCommand event of the Gridview , and access the CommandArgument of that row like following:

```
  protected void GV_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {
     //You get the ID of that specific row that you have selected :
     string ID=e.CommandArgument.ToString();
     //Here you write your code !          For example a select query to get that row from database by the ID you have  gained in above line of code
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give me example to event GridView1_RowCreated() ?

Comment: The above code is an example ! did you undrestand It ? what do you exacly want to know ?

Comment: name of column where was selected row

Comment: I don`t need event with button because this is very simple I need value item which I clicked in table.